# IOS 7 - css - html height - 100% = 692px

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari, ios7

I have a weird bug on iPad iOS7 landscape mode.

What i was able to investigate is that in iOS7 window.outerHeight is 692px and 
window.innerHeight 672px; while in previous versions both values are 672px.

Even though my `<html>` and `<body>` tags have height 100% there seems to be space for scrolling, and the weird thing is that this problem only shows up on landscpae

You can see what i am talking about by visiting t.cincodias.com, for example, in a iOS 7 iPad the footer bar (or the header sometimes) will be cut. But on previous iOS versions the content displays fine at fullscreen.

Even when i set the height of both tags to `height: 672px !important` and `position:absolute; bottom: 0;`, you can still scroll the content vertically by touching an iframe (the ads are iframes).

I'm running the release candidate version of iOS7

thanks for any help.

Comment: sorry about that, it was correctly spelled of course, and there are no margins or paddings

Comment: Here's a nice hack that actually works for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19449123/795563

Comment: On a side note: this bug seems to be fixed on iOS8. Workarounds should only target iOS7.

Answer (score 16):

I used this JavaScript solution for solving that problem:

```
if (
    navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad;.*CPU.*OS 7_\d/i) && 
    window.innerHeight != document.documentElement.clientHeight
) {
    var fixViewportHeight = function() {
        document.documentElement.style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
        if (document.body.scrollTop !== 0) {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", fixViewportHeight, false);
    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", fixViewportHeight, false);
    fixViewportHeight();

    document.body.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(0,0,0)";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that! I thought I was going crazy for a second today while testing a UI I am building out.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, is, at least, usefull. But, what about if I want to run this function only when the soft keyboard are shown? Any idea? Thank you very much!

Comment: You can only detect that soft keyboard is shown, if you use Apache Cordova/Phonegap and enabling viewport resizing when soft keyboard appears.

Answer (score 15):

I believe this is a bug in iOS 7 - if you rotate it to portrait mode, it sets both (innerHeight/outerHeight) to the same value. If it isn't a bug, then portrait mode has one because the behavior isn't consistent.

You could detect iOS 7/mobile Safari and use window.innerHeight if iOS 7.

Comment: Ww are also hoping it's just a bug, we are opting right now for a specific style for iOS7 but we were hoping that this wouldn't be the final solution, thanks for the answer anyway

Comment: Have you found anything related to it? I am having the same problem in Landscape mode, it ruins every media query (for ios7 landscape on ipad/ipad mini/ipod latest gen) I am running and I've noticed it to the emulator as well. What kind of media queries do you use (if you do)?

Comment: @Panagiotis, you can try something like this:
1. set $(window).height(672);
2. call window.scrollTo(0, 0); every time user try scroll the whole page (with some locking algorithm), or try to unbind scroll event.

Comment: Actually my problem was a duplicate meta tag. I removed the offensive code and it worked fine. Thanks though.

Comment: @Panagiotis Can you say which meta tag generated the problem?

Comment: There was a double definition of meta viewport that passed our checks.

Comment: It appears to a bug. I made a test case at http://jonfabritius.net/tests/792_reduction.html and submitted that to http://bugreport.apple.com.

Is this similar to what you're experiencing?

Comment: @JonFabritius: is it possible to subscribe somehow to that bugreport?

Answer (score 7):

I'll combine the answers. Thanks all!

You can do something like this:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad;.*CPU.*OS 7_\d/i)) {
    $('#yourDivID').height(window.innerHeight);
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

The window.scrollTo solves the issue of the bar overlapping in landscape when rotating.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I reproduce the same problem in iOS 8.

Here is my solution.

I listened **resize**, **scroll**, **orientationChange** event, to ensure when user trigger screen size change, will call reset height function.

I wrote a **debounce** to prevent multiple call.

And It's in a **closure** and **no dependent** (no jQuery).

```
(function(){
  var setViewportHeight = (function(){
    function debounced(){
      document.documentElement.style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
      if (document.body.scrollTop !== 0) {
          window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      }
    }
    var cancelable = null;

    return function(){
      cancelable && clearTimeout(cancelable);
      cancelable = setTimeout(debounced, 100);
    };
  })();

  //ipad safari
  if(/iPad/.test(navigator.platform) && /Safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){  
    window.addEventListener("resize", setViewportHeight, false);
    window.addEventListener("scroll", setViewportHeight, false);
    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", setViewportHeight, false);
    setViewportHeight();
  }
})();
```