# window.innerheight returns bad value on ios7 (iphone4)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios7, window, viewport

i'm working on a web app which has layout constraints set by javascript, it mainly works around calculations on the `window.innerHeight` but i get a bad value only on my iphone4 with iOS7.

this is a sample screenshot (as you can see at the bottom, the text is cut):
[image]

what i get is a `window.innerHeight` of `568px` instead of `480px` and this is breaking my layout.

[image]

anyone encountered any error like this?

i've my viewport set like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui" />
```

any help is GREATLY appreciated. thanks :)

Comment: Are you using safari?
If this is the case, you need to add around 30px due to the top safari bar, however have you tried to use document,height???

Comment: it's not a matter of adding, but subtracting. i have an extra 88px calculated by javascript that i don't need and that are incorrect (iphone4 window height is 480px). i tried document height, still 568px instead of 480px

Comment: Your are right, you need to subtract it. However, 568px is the landscape width of an iphone 5. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6724

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855642/ios-7-css-html-height-100-692px

Comment: sorry that didn't help :\