# CSS Rendering bug in landscape mode of mobile Safari?

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile, safari

When in landscape mode, my iPad2 puts the bottom border below the fold in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/L7zgLk5w/show/

I got confirmed, that this happens on iPhones in landscape mode too.

All other devices I tested show a the red borders on all sides of the screen without scrolling.

Is it a rendering bug in Mobile Safari?

Here is the code:

```
html,body,table
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

td
{
 border: 1px solid red;
}

<table>
 <tr><td>top</td></tr>
 <tr><td>middle</td></tr>
 <tr><td>bottom</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a bug in IOS7:

[iOS 7 iPad Safari Landscape innerHeight/outerHeight layout issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012135/ios-7-ipad-safari-landscape-innerheight-outerheight-layout-issue)

[IOS 7 - css - html height - 100% = 692px](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855642/ios-7-css-html-height-100-692px)

https://gist.github.com/benhuson/8664741