# Ipad scroll reached bottom condition not met

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, scroll

I have a requirement to change the footer if the scroll reached bottom of the page. So I used

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())
```

condition to check whether the scroll has reached the bottom or not. But this condition is not getting met in an Ipad, but works on desktop.

Is there something different to check to find if scroll has reached bottom? How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This could be because of a bug with ios7. You can check this answer if it helps
[IOS 7 - css - html height - 100% = 692px](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855642/ios-7-css-html-height-100-692px)