# :Active style appears as being applied to random divs on tap in Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios7, mobile-safari

[image]

Upon release of a button, one of the other buttons flickers on its `:active` styling. You can see in my gif that it seems to only happen when clicking the *function* and *advanced* divs. ( tapping on the *design* div seems to behave normally ).

**Some backstory**: This problem only arose after adding `html{ position:fixed }` to my CSS to fix this problem: [iPhone viewport height too large in landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664403/iphone-viewport-height-too-large-in-landscape-mode)

I was hoping for a CSS solution to this problem that doesn't reproduce my previous problem with the iphone viewport. But of course, Vanilla JavaScript is welcome.

This is happening on my Iphone 4S, running IOS7 and only when the phone is in landscape mode **AND** the Safari UI( The address bar and bottom toolbar ) are active. Only then, does this problem happen.

```css
html, body{
  margin:0; padding:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:#fff; 
  font-family:Arial; overflow:hidden;
}
html{ position:fixed; }
p{ margin:0; padding:0; } nav{ height:100%; }

.vCenter{
  position:relative; top:50%; -webkit-transform:translateY( -50% );
  -ms-transform:translateY( -50% ); transform:translateY( -50% );
}
.option{
  margin:0; width:33.33%; height:100%; background:#transparent;
  text-align:center; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:110%; cursor:pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout:none; -webkit-user-select:none; 
  -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select:none; user-select:none; float:left;
  
  -webkit-transition: background 0.5s ease, color 0.5s ease, font-size 0.5s ease;
  transition: background 0.5s ease, color 0.5s ease, font-size 0.5s ease;
}
.option:active, .option:hover{
  background:#0bb; color:#eee;
}

@media( min-height:299px ) and ( max-height:371px ){
  .option{
    width:100%; height:33.33%; box-sizing:border-box;
  }
  #function{
    border-bottom:none;
  }
}
@media( height:372px ){
  .option{
    width:100%; height:124px; box-sizing:border-box;
  }
  #function{
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
  }
}
@media( min-height:373px ) and ( max-height:568px ){
  .option{
    width:100%; height:33.4%; box-sizing:border-box;
  }
  #function{
    border-bottom:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="author" content="Lynel Hudson">
  <meta name="desciption" content="Front End Reference for Anyone">
  <title>WEB</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css">
</head>
<body ontouchstart="">
  <nav>
    <div id="design" class="option">
      <p class="vCenter">design</p>
    </div>
    <div id="function" class="option">
      <p class="vCenter">function</p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="rule"></div>
    
    <div id="advanced" class="option">
      <p class="vCenter">advanced</p>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Link to page: http://www.lynelhudson.com/web/so/

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be you have an overlay issue. Which is causing the problem.

```
 .option{
    width:100%; height:33.4%; box-sizing:border-box;
  }
```

You've declared these elements to overlap on another in this instance. Have you tried declaring 20% height just to make sure that you're not experiencing  an overlap issue?

Also, I'm wondering why you chose html { position: fixed; } over simply stating the body to be 100% in height of the viewport and to then diallow scaling. This guarantee that it always stays 1 zoom and that your height is always 100%. You could add in a overflow: hidden; if paranoia sets in though. As you have it set now your intended design would still be wrecked upon browser setting or accidental zooming.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: I’d really love to know from the OP whether some of your points yielded any new insights into the issue.